# How to programmaticaly put ImageView to the top of RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to programmatically set **X** and **Y** position of an `ImageView` inside a `RelativeLayout`.

I'm able to set the X position, but the Y position seems not working. The `ImageView` is shown almost in the middle of the screen.

I read many posts here on stackoverflow and tried many codes, but no one works.

I show you my original code, without showing all my attempts.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams viewlp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    viewlp.height = drawableHeight;
    viewlp.width = drawableWidth;
    imageView.setX(Xposition);
    imageView.setY(Yposition);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(viewlp);



    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(imageView, lp);
```

Here you can see where I have to put the `ImageView`.

[image]

Does anybody know what's my error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this way

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(activity);
ImageView imgeView = new ImageView(activity);


RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

rl.addView(imgeView, lp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP); add this line
```